# How to mock the return of a public method called in a private method inSpring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a private method called `getSubject` in a class which i have just implemented. I am trying to carry out a unit test on the private method but my issue is that the private method `getSubject` is calling another method `getSubjectOracle()` (note:`getSubjectOracle` is a public method in a jar file) which returns a `String` subject. A pseoudocode is shown below:

```
public class Service{

    private oracleDao

    //setter for oracle dao avilable


    private String getSubject(String id,Stringountry){

        String subject = oracleDao.getSubjectOracle(String id,String country)

        return subject;

    }

}
```

Any idea how i can mock the return of the method `oracleDao.getSubjectOracle(String id,String country)` in order to carry unit test for method `getSubject(String id, String country)` pls?

I have search online of helpful resouces but could not get any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to write a setter for oracleDao. There you can set a mock instead of the real thing. For example write your own oracleDao that does what you want.
In the @Before method you would inject the mock oracleDao.

All this is nicer with a framework like Mockito. It would look like this:

```
@Mock
YourDaoThing mock;

@Before
public setUp(){
  MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this);
  service = new Service();
  service.setDao(mock);
}

@Test
public testGetSubject(){
  String someString = "whatever";
  when(mock.getSubjectOracle(id,country)).thenReturn(someString)

  assertEquals(expect, service.callToTheMethodYouTest())

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the response i am following your example but according to your example how can i make method callToTheMethodYouTest() visible since it is private?apologies i know it was not part of the question.

Comment: Well, usually you test all public methods. I suspect that some public method in your class is going to call the private method. This is what I meant with callToTheMethodYouTest() which is supposed to call the private method you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test `Service`, then you have to mock `oracleDao` as well and make its `getSubjectOracle()` method return the String you want.

I'm assuming you aren't testing `getSubject()` but a method that calls `getSubject()`.